# TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} ' TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to write JSON data contained in an array in a file but I'm not able to solve the issue reported in the title.
Here my code:

```
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://ethans_fake_twitter_site.surge.sh/'
response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
tweetArr = []
for tweet in content.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "tweetcontainer"}):
    tweetObject = {
        "author": tweet.find('h2', attrs={"class": "author"}).text.encode('utf-8'),
        "date": tweet.find('h5', attrs={"class": "dateTime"}).text.encode('utf-8'),
        "tweet": tweet.find('p', attrs={"class": "content"}).text.encode('utf-8'),
        "likes": tweet.find('p', attrs={"class": "likes"}).text.encode('utf-8'),
        "shares": tweet.find('p', attrs={"class": "shares"}).text.encode('utf-8')
    }
    tweetArr.append(tweetObject)

#print(tweetArr)

with open('twitterData.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(tweetArr, outfile)
```

This is the tweetArr content:

```
[{'author': b'jimmyfallon', 'date': b'17/01/2017 13:47', 'tweet': b'Tonight: @MichaelKeaton, @ninadobrev, music from @The_xx, and more! #FallonTonight', 'likes': b'Likes  184', 'shares': b'Shares  42'}, {'author': b'jimmyfallon', 'date': b'17/01/2017 12:55', 'tweet': b'.@michaelstrahan and @BryceDHoward take on @questlove and I in an intense game of Pyramid  #FallonTonight', 'likes': b'Likes  402', 'shares': b'Shares  60'},....}]
```

Comment: `text.encode('utf-8')` will encode the string into bytes.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean that I have to delete text.encode('utf-8') in order to solve the issue ?

Comment: Why do you encode your data into bytes in the first place?

Comment: I was following a tutorial, but you are right, it's no a specific reason to do that in fact deleting the encoding I have solved the issue. The question I have right now is: could I  solve the same issue by using json.dump(tweetArr.decode('utf-8'), outfile) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `.encode('utf-8')` part, it doesn't make any sense.

```py
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://ethans_fake_twitter_site.surge.sh/'
response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
tweetArr = []
for tweet in content.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "tweetcontainer"}):
    tweetObject = {
        "author": tweet.find('h2', attrs={"class": "author"}).text,
        "date": tweet.find('h5', attrs={"class": "dateTime"}).text,
        "tweet": tweet.find('p', attrs={"class": "content"}).text,
        "likes": tweet.find('p', attrs={"class": "likes"}).text,
        "shares": tweet.find('p', attrs={"class": "shares"}).text
    }
    tweetArr.append(tweetObject)

with open('twitterData.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(tweetArr, outfile)
```

Comment: Yeah you are right, I was following a tutorial without any critic sense and I was not able to find the issue by myself. Thank you